# Handling Errors from HttpWebRequest.GetResponse

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, sms

I'm having a ridiculous time trying to get an SMS API working ([ZeepMobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com), if you're interested) with .NET... I've been around .NET for a few years, but with all this social networking and API stuff, I need to get into the HttpWebRequest a bit. I'm new at it, but not completely new; I was able to hook up my site to Twitter without too much fuss (ie, I was able to modify someone's code to work for me).

Anyways, the way their API works is to send an SMS message, you send them a POST and they respond back to you. I can send it just fine, but every time I do, rather than echo back something helpful to figure out what the error is, I get the Yellow Error Page Of Death (YEPOD) saying something to the effect of "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." This occurs on my line:

```
'...creation of httpwebrequest here...'
Dim myWebResponse As WebResponse
myWebResponse = request.GetResponse() '<--- error line
```

Is there any way to simply receive the error from the server rather than have the webserver throw an exception and give me the YEPOD?

Or better yet, can anyone post a working example of their Zeep code? :)

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here's my whole code block:

```
Public Shared Function SendTextMessage(ByVal username As String, _
ByVal txt As String) As String
    Dim content As String = "user_id=" + _
username + "&body=" + Current.Server.UrlEncode(txt)

    Dim httpDate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("r")
    Dim canonicalString As String = API_KEY & httpDate & content

    Dim encoding As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    Dim hmacSha As New HMACSHA1(encoding.GetBytes(SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))

    Dim hash() As Byte = hmacSha.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(canonicalString))
    Dim b64 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(hash)

    'connect with zeep'
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(_
"https://api.zeepmobile.com/messaging/2008-07-14/send_message"), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = False

    ' set the authorization levels'
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Zeep " & API_KEY & ":" & b64)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = content.Length

    ' set up and write to stream'
    Dim reqStream As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
    reqStream.Write(content)
    reqStream.Close()
    Dim msg As String = ""
    msg = reqStream.ToString

    Dim myWebResponse As WebResponse
    Dim myResponseStream As Stream
    Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader

    myWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    myResponseStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
    myStreamReader = New StreamReader(myResponseStream)
    msg = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    myStreamReader.Close()
    myResponseStream.Close()

    ' Close the WebResponse'
    myWebResponse.Close()
    Return msg
End Function
```

Comment: ps, is there a way to just view what the headers are of both the send and the receive? i'm trying to use fiddler but either i don't know how to use it or it's just completely unhelpful...

Comment: Please provide your request code

Comment: ps - for those trying to get your zeep code to work, the above code will return a 400 Bad Request: "Message time differs to much from server clock or Date header was not supplied." Still working on that, since you can't modify the "Date" header...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
'' set up request
Try
    Using response = req.GetResponse()
        '' success in here
    End Using
Catch ex As WebException
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Status)
    If ex.Response IsNot Nothing Then
        '' can use ex.Response.Status, .StatusDescription
        If ex.Response.ContentLength <> 0 Then
            Using stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader = New StreamReader(stream)
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd())
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End If
End Try
```

---

C# version

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
// set up request
try {
    using (var response = req.GetResponse()) {
        // success in here
        }
}
catch (WebException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Status);
    if (ex.Response != null) {
        // can use ex.Response.Status, .StatusDescription
        if (ex.Response.ContentLength != 0) {
            using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream()) {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

---

Here's your code, modified a bit:

```
Try
    'connect with zeep'
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create( _
"https://api.zeepmobile.com/messaging/2008-07-14/send_message"), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = False

    ' set the authorization levels'
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Zeep " & API_KEY & ":" & b64)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = content.Length

    ' set up and write to stream'
    Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        Using requestWriter As New StreamWriter(requestStream)
            requestWriter.Write(content)
        End Using
    End Using

    Using myWebResponse As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Using myResponseStream As Stream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
            Using myStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(myResponseStream)
                Return myStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As WebException
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Status)
    If ex.Response IsNot Nothing Then
        '' can use ex.Response.Status, .StatusDescription
        If ex.Response.ContentLength <> 0 Then
            Using stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader = New StreamReader(stream)
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd())
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
    End If
End Try
```

---

Dumping headers:

```
Dim headers As WebHeaderCollection = request.Headers
' Displays the headers. Works with HttpWebResponse.Headers as well
Debug.WriteLine(headers.ToString())

' And so does this
For Each hdr As String In headers
    Dim headerMessage As String = String.Format("{0}: {1}", hdr, headers(hdr))
    Debug.WriteLine(headerMessage)
Next
```

Comment: ok i got the VB version working and i was able to read the error message... as a bonus, is there any way to read my OUTPUT headers and everything before/as it's being sent out?

Comment: Using is like "using" in C# - it makes sure that the Dispose method gets called on what's inside it, so the first one makes sure response.Dispose is called, even if there's an exception. I'm about to post a changed version of your code.

Comment: thanks... your posted update to my code is pretty much what i have... I figured out why I'm getting the error, so now I need to find out what my output headers look like... any way to check to see what those look like?

Comment: You should be able to iterate over request.Headers. I don't recall what type you get back from the For Each, but  you should be able to get them all.

Comment: thanks a lot... while it doesn't fix my issue w/getting the durn thing to work, it definitely helps me work with it by being able to see the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's normal for a `WebException` to be thrown when the request returns a 4xx or 5xx code.  You just need to catch it and handle it appropriately.

Have you looked at the `Headers` collection after the call to `GetResponse`?

> it just throws an exception at the GetResponse... how would I check the headers after that?

```
Try
    myWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Catch x As WebException
    log, cleanup, etc.
Finally
    log/inspect headers?
End Try
```

Comment: i can't get that far... it just throws an exception at the GetResponse... how would I check the headers after that?

Comment: From the 400 "bad request" error code, I assumed that the exception was thrown in response to getting an error from the other server.  Wouldn't an error in your code cause a 500?

Comment: do you have actual code for checking headers? i've tried so many things by now my head is swirling... thanks :(

Comment: I'm sure I could find something, but I'm equally sure I'm not allowed to post it, sorry.  If you do get a WebException, then the actual error sent from the other server should be in WebException.Response and you can find the headers for it in WebException.Response.Headers.  If you get a successful response, the headers will be in myWebResponse.Headers.  I don't recall if request.Headers is filled in with the ones that were actually sent, or only used to specify your own to be added.